# delpoy spark app to remote spark master: get error-java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException

Tags: apache-spark

For one spark app, I use "sbt run" in my own laptop to submit the job to remote master;
I met the problem as follows:

```
ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread
Thread[appclient-registration-retry-thread,5,run-main-group-0]
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@65d92aad rejected from
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@1480f818[Running, pool size = 1,
active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
```

Comment: how and what command did you used for submitting the application? and is your remote cluster accessible and ready to accept the jobs?